# How do I make instances of enemies spawn after every three keypress movements?

Tags: game-maker

I am making a game, where two zombies will spawn after every three moves my character makes. The problem is that I have no idea how to do this.

I have my character moving correctly, in each key press event, so I want the game to count each time one of these events are triggered, and perform the action after every third trigger. Perhaps I need a global variable/counter that can count these events?

How do I make instances of enemies spawn after every three keypress movements?

Comment: Hi Toby, and welcome to Game Dev Stack Exchange. Check out our [tour] to see how we work. Please tag your Game Maker questions with [game-maker]; we prefer people do not put tags in titles. Also, when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 2):

Here is some pseudocode:

```
If keypress do
    KeyPressCounter++
End
If KeyPressCounter%3 == 0 do
    Action ()
End
```

This preforms a modulo operation which will detect numbers divisible by 3.

Comment: This doesn't appear to give any guidance on how to do this in game maker.

Comment: StackExchange is not here to code for you, this pseudocode has valid logic and can be applied in GML. I would recommend @DeaSTL to extend his explaination to help OP understand why this works.

Comment: Besides, i've never used game maker but i've used other libraries.

Comment: Simpler: `if keypresscounter++%3` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create this type of event, I suggest this :

If your character moves with the directional keys, then create four Keypress event : one for each key (Up, Down, Right, Left). Create a variable in `Create` event, and increment this variable in the four event previously created. Then, in the `Step` event, check if the variable is equal at 3. If yes, do your action and set the variable at 0. If not, do nothing.

Here what it looks in code :

Create event :

```
number_key_pressed=0;
```

Key press left event :

```
number_key_pressed+=1;
```

Key press right event :

```
number_key_pressed+=1;
```

Key press up event :

```
number_key_pressed+=1;
```

Key press down event :

```
number_key_pressed+=1;
```

Step event :

```
if(number_key_pressed==3)
{action();
number_key_pressed=0;}
```